# How to find missing elements between two elements in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list as follows:

```
['1', '5', '6', '7', '10']
```

I want to find the missing element between two elements in the above list. For example, I want to get the missing elements between `'1'` and `'5'`, i.e. `'2'`, `'3'` and `'4'`. Another example, there are no elements between `'5'` and `'6'`, so it doesn't need to return anything.

Following the list above, I expect it to return a list like this:

```
['2', '3', '4', '8', '9']
```

My code:

```
# Sort elements in a list
input_list.sort()

# Remove duplicates from a list
input_list = list(dict.fromkeys(input_list))
```

How to return the above list? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @DanielHao thanks for your comment, I didn't share my code because I don't think the code is relevant to this question. Also, my question is how to return the expected list written in my question

Comment: Seems that you're a frequent contributor here... so it's just a friendly reminder to share the effort, is it fair to ask?   "To protect your own reputation."

Comment: @DanielHao I'm happy to share but other parts are with different context. In overall, I have a long list after processing, followed by `sort`, `duplicates removal` and lastly the identification of `missing elements between 2 elements` as posted here. Would be happy to share the code for `sort` and `duplicates removal` in the post above if required.

Comment: Fair point.  Agreed. but you can still post the mini code - 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   Anyway, that's just suggestion - *it's up to you.*

Comment: I thought your question was fine. It said what you needed to accomplish clearly. Since it was more of a task than troubleshooting it left the doors open for your repliers to write their answer in their own code style, and be creative. This post is just at 1 hour old and you have 5 excellent answers. If anything, I would argue that stack should take your question and weigh it against their "rules". This post was fun. Generally, it isn't very much fun. It's more like a burden I accept.

Comment: Since order doesn't matter, it seems like what you want instead is the list of all the numbers between the smallest and largest in the original list (exclusive), with some filtered out. As an optimization, sorting and de-duplicating the list is unnecessary, since you're finding the min and max regardless, and the generation of in-between numbers will always be sorted.

Comment: I noticed you changed your accepted answer to mine, and I also know that you seemed concerned about performance. I'm just curious if mine was the fastest one?

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Actually I don't know. All I know is that `for` loops are slow in other programming languages like Flutter, so I assume Python's `for` loops are also slow. So I changed the accepted answer to yours

Comment: Heard that. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qgevy75co8c). It's mCoding benchmarking all the various python loops.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy ok, I'll test the speed of running code for all answers

Comment: I wasn't necessarily implying you should do all that work. I was giving you the best video I know of to give you confidence in your loop choices. You're going to have to use them eventually.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy maybe

Comment: @OneMadGypsy five answers to this question are valid, but I don't know which one I should accept…

Comment: Well, I don't think you accepted the wrong one, and I'm not saying that because it's mine. I'm saying that because it works, it's not convoluted, and it's not obvious. You didn't just solve your problem with my method, I showed you a different way to even think about it. I won't be mad if you choose differently, but you actually only have 2 answer, though. 4 of the same thing and mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `range` and `set` and skip iteration altogether.

```
#original data
data = ['1', '5', '6', '7', '10']

#convert to list[int]
L    = list(map(int, data))

#get a from/to count
R    = range(min(L), max(L)+1)

#remove duplicates and convert back to list[str]
out  = list(map(str, set(R) ^ set(L)))

print(out)
```

Comment: @MyCar ~ All of the answers work :D, and you're welcome.

Comment: Yes, I tested all answers and all works. Just, there is something wrong with your code, my expected result is `['2', '3', '4', '8', '9']` but the actual result is `[2, 3, 4, 8, 9]`

Comment: Yeah, this one doesn't convert the list back to strings, but it's a simple fix

Comment: @MyCar - woops, I fixed it.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy, I tested it and it shows the expected result

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Since this requires no `for` loop, would this be most ideal or optimized for performance, says consume less memory resource?

Comment: @MyCar ~ Honestly, I don't know. I didn't worry about speed. I only worried about making my answer different. You could use `timeit` or some such thing on all the versions and find out.

Comment: This is clever but I'm not sure why you use symmetric difference `set(R) ^ set(L)`? Just `set(R) - set(L)` would seem more logical/efficient (since it should always be the case that L is a subset of R).

Comment: @wim - The best answer I have for you is: I play with a lot of bytes and the syntax felt natural. I fully understand your argument, though. I think changing it at this point would be "6 of one and half of a dozen of the other".

Answer (score 2):

If you iterate in pairs, it is easy to detect and fill in the gaps:

```
L = ['1', '5', '6', '7', '10']
result = []
for left, right in zip(L, L[1:]):
    left, right = int(left), int(right)
    result += map(str, range(left + 1, right))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `range()` function to generate the missing numbers, and maybe use [`itertools.pairwise()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) to easily compare to the previous number. Since Python 3.10, `pairwise` is better than `zip(arr, arr[1:])` because pairwise is implemented in the C layer, and does not make a copy of lists.

```py
import itertools
arr = ['1', '5', '6', '7', '10']

new_arr = []

for p, c in itertools.pairwise(arr):
    prev, curr = int(p), int(c)
    if (prev + 1) != curr:
        new_arr.extend([str(i) for i in range(prev + 1, curr)])
```

Comment: This code will not work - because *prev* is string.  Do you ever run it?

Comment: Would be nicer to just to it before the checking (and after done) - ```L = [int(x) for x in L]```   L is the array.   nice use *pairwise* here. +1

Comment: @DanielHao this design has no additional space complexity, but converting the whole list at the beginning is also an option.

Comment: @Dash Whether pairwise is better than zipping is entirely dependent on the size of the data. For the small example in the question, using pairwise is significantly slower than zipping with a copy.

Comment: @wim I ran the code with `%%timeit`, comparing `pairwise(arr)` vs `zip(arr, arr[1:])`, and they're not much different, `pairwise` is maybe 5% faster (2.23 µs vs 2.38µs). Do you have a source for pairwise being slower?

Comment: [Here](https://dpaste.com/29XXERJRT) was my timing. Pairwise ended up about 10% slower. In hindsight, it may have been more due to the map vs list comprehension, than due to the iteration!

Comment: @wim Try running [this](https://dpaste.com/F2469CM3K) where the only change is zip and pairwise, not how the array is extended. I agree though, my technique for adding to the end of the array is suboptimal.

Comment: Hmm, yep, it looks like itertools is faster there. It's still data dependent though, for a list of length ~15 the copy+zip seems to overtake again (I can't think of any explanation why)

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not an issue, you can use a simple nested `for` loop:

```
input_list = ['1', '5', '6', '7', '10']

missing_list = []

for ind in range(0, len(input_list)-1):

    el_0 = int(input_list[ind])
    el_f = int(input_list[ind+1])

    for num in range(el_0 + 1, el_f):
        missing_list.append(str(num))
```

The above assumes that the numbers are integers. The first loop is something not recommended - the loop iterates using the length of the list instead of constructs like `enumerate`. I used it here for its simplicity.

Comment: `if num < el_f:` will always be true there.

Comment: @wim - fixed, thank you! It was a bit past my waking hours..

Answer (score 0):

Using a classic for loop and `range()` method and also for one-liner fans:

```
arr = ['1', '5', '6', '7', '10']
ans = []

for i in range(len(arr) - 1): ans += map(str, list(range(int(arr[i]) + 1, int(arr[i + 1]))))
    
print(ans)
```

outputs: `['2', '3', '4', '8', '9']`

Comment: @wim - I fully agree. That's why it doesn't have any votes. IMO, this should not be the selected answer. Aside from the code there is no explanation or effort of any kind.